# Observable<Any> transformation to Observable<Bar[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm pretty new to angular, I'm trying to transform result of an Observable any to Observable<Bar[]> but I have an error: Type Bar is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput any

```
find(id: string): Observable<Bar[]> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map(data => data.result.entities)
          switchMap((data) => {
            let bar: Bar = {
              id: data.field,
              entity: data
            };
            return bar;
          })
        );
}
```

Any idea how to do ?

Comment: why swpichmap????? is `data.result.entities` an `Observable` ??????

Comment: Not data.result.entities is an observable but this.findFoo is ☝

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like so to be **Typescript** compliant :

```
find(id: string): Observable<Array<Bar>> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map((response: Array<any>) => {
            return response.result.entities.map((entity: any) => {
              return {
                id: entity.field,
                entity: entity
              } as Bar
            }
          }
        );
}
```

By the way, why does the `find` method return (Array of) `any`? Couldn't this be type safe as well?

Comment: `new Bar() {` is not typescript compliant :D

Comment: and first map's typing is wrong too, `data.result.entities` is the array, not `result`

Comment: My Bar is an interface, but it works!

Comment: then it should be only `{id:x, enity:y}`

Comment: @Random corrected your comments. Thanx! 

Answer (score 1):

The [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator should return an observable. You don't really need it in your case. You can just specify type on your [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator, which will apply the projection and emit the results. Something like this:

```
find(id: string): Observable<Bar[]> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map(data<any, Bar[]> => data.result.entities)
        );
}
```

Here's a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-go2zu8).

EDIT: Regarding mapping to different fields - it should be pretty much the same with included [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the actual array (note - on the array, not observable), e.g.

```
find(id: string): Observable<Bar[]> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map(data<any, Bar[]> => data.result.entities.map(x => {
            return {id: x.bar, label: x.foo}
          })
        );
}
```

Updated stackblitz from the comment [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9c2dsz).

Comment: Thank for answear me, to take back you exemple: https://rxjs-cokwwt.stackblitz.io
any and bar dont have the same field, I want transform entities to Bar

Comment: I've updated the answer to include transformation to interface.

Answer (score 1):

just change your switchMap to a map:

```
find(id: string): Observable<Bar[]> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map((data: Foo) => data.result.entities),
          map((entities: FooEntity[]) => {
            return entities.map((entity:FooEntity) => {
              const bar: Bar = {
                id: entity.field,
                entity: entity
              };
              return bar;
            });
          })
        );
}
```

then you can also combine those 2 maps:

```
find(id: string): Observable<Bar[]> {
    return this.findFoo(id)
        .pipe(
          map((data: Foo) => data.result.entities.map((entity: FooEntity) => {
            const bar: Bar = {
              id: entity.field,
              entity: entity
            };
            return bar;
          }))
        );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your function returns `Observable<Bar[]>`, you have to return in your statement also this type like so:

```
let bars: Bar[] = [];
bars.push(bar);

return of(bars);
```